# Apache Axis2 application/json not return a well format json object

Tags: json, xml, apache, apache-axis, hierarchical-data

i have an API service deployed on wso2 enterprise integrator console that send a request on a db for a select.
It returns the data of the hierarchical structure
 in xml format :

```
    <cdcList xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<cdc>
<idCdc xmlns="">2</idCdc>
<idCdcParent xmlns=""/>
<cdcName xmlns="">Roma</cdcName>
<order xmlns="">1</order>
<isUsed xmlns="">false</isUsed>
<cdcList>
<cdc>
<idCdc xmlns="">5</idCdc>
<idCdcParent xmlns="">2</idCdcParent>
<cdcName xmlns="">Progetti</cdcName>
<order xmlns="">2</order>
<isUsed xmlns="">false</isUsed>
<cdcList>
<cdc>
<idCdc xmlns="">17</idCdc>
<idCdcParent xmlns="">5</idCdcParent>
<cdcName xmlns="">testGP</cdcName>
<order xmlns="">1</order>
<isUsed xmlns="">false</isUsed>
<cdcList/>
</cdc>
<cdc>
<idCdc xmlns="">18</idCdc>
<idCdcParent xmlns="">5</idCdcParent>
<cdcName xmlns="">testGPS</cdcName>
<order xmlns="">2</order>
<isUsed xmlns="">false</isUsed>
<cdcList/>
</cdc>
</cdcList>
</cdc>
</cdcList>
</cdc>
<cdc>
<idCdc xmlns="">3</idCdc>
<idCdcParent xmlns=""/>
<cdcName xmlns="">Milano</cdcName>
<order xmlns="">4</order>
<isUsed xmlns="">false</isUsed>
<cdcList>
<cdc>
<idCdc xmlns="">7</idCdc>
<idCdcParent xmlns="">3</idCdcParent>
<cdcName xmlns="">l</cdcName>
<order xmlns="">4</order>
<isUsed xmlns="">false</isUsed>
<cdcList/>
</cdc>
</cdcList>
</cdc>
<cdc>
<idCdc xmlns="">4</idCdc>
<idCdcParent xmlns=""/>
<cdcName xmlns="">Napoli</cdcName>
<order xmlns="">5</order>
<isUsed xmlns="">false</isUsed>
<cdcList>
<cdc>
<idCdc xmlns="">9</idCdc>
<idCdcParent xmlns="">4</idCdcParent>
<cdcName xmlns="">cccc</cdcName>
<order xmlns="">6</order>
<isUsed xmlns="">false</isUsed>
<cdcList/>
</cdc>
</cdcList>
</cdc>
</cdcList>
```

The service use the application/json of the Apache Axis2 engine that trasform the output from xml to json.
The problem is that if the parent object have more than one child it work well but if there is only one or no one child it not return a well json format output.
I tried to check the java class of the Apache Axis2 engine for found where it manage the brackets in json array but i don't find a solution.
This is the output of the API service:

```
{"cdcList":{"cdc":[{"idCdc":2,"idCdcParent":null,"cdcName":"Roma","order":1,"isUsed":false,"cdcList":{"cdc":{"idCdc":5,"idCdcParent":2,"cdcName":"Progetti","order":2,"isUsed":false,"cdcList":{"cdc":[{"idCdc":17,"idCdcParent":5,"cdcName":"testGP","order":1,"isUsed":false,"cdcList":null},{"idCdc":18,"idCdcParent":5,"cdcName":"testGPS","order":2,"isUsed":false,"cdcList":null}]}}}},{"idCdc":3,"idCdcParent":null,"cdcName":"Milano","order":4,"isUsed":false,"cdcList":{"cdc":{"idCdc":7,"idCdcParent":3,"cdcName":"l","order":4,"isUsed":false,"cdcList":null}}},{"idCdc":4,"idCdcParent":null,"cdcName":"Napoli","order":5,"isUsed":false,"cdcList":{"cdc":{"idCdc":9,"idCdcParent":4,"cdcName":"cccc","order":6,"isUsed":false,"cdcList":null}}}]}}
```

and this is how i would like it will be :

```
{
"cdcList": [{
        "idCdc": 2,
        "idCdcParent": null,
        "cdcName": "Roma",
        "order": 1,
        "isUsed": false,
        "cdcList": [{
            "idCdc": 5,
            "idCdcParent": 2,
            "cdcName": "Progetti",
            "order": 2,
            "isUsed": false,
            "cdcList": [{
                    "idCdc": 17,
                    "idCdcParent": 5,
                    "cdcName": "testGP",
                    "order": 1,
                    "isUsed": false,
                    "cdcList": null
                },
                {
                    "idCdc": 18,
                    "idCdcParent": 5,
                    "cdcName": "testGPS",
                    "order": 2,
                    "isUsed": false,
                    "cdcList": null
                }
            ]



        }]
    },
    {
        "idCdc": 3,
        "idCdcParent": null,
        "cdcName": "Milano",
        "order": 4,
        "isUsed": false,
        "cdcList": [{

            "idCdc": 7,
            "idCdcParent": 3,
            "cdcName": "l",
            "order": 4,
            "isUsed": false,
            "cdcList": null
        }]
    },
    {
        "idCdc": 4,
        "idCdcParent": null,
        "cdcName": "Napoli",
        "order": 5,
        "isUsed": false,
        "cdcList": [{

            "idCdc": 9,
            "idCdcParent": 4,
            "cdcName": "cccc",
            "order": 6,
            "isUsed": false,
            "cdcList": null
        }]
    }
]
```

}

Note the brackets and the lack of the "cdc" items.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know the problem is that the XML to JSON converter cannot tell if a single XML element is intentional and should be converted to a JSON object, or it is a list of one and should wrap the object in a list.

The easiest way to do this would be to use an XSLT transform to add xml-multiple processing instructions before each cdcList element.

You want you XML to look like this before converting it to JSON

```
<?xml-multiple cdcList?>
<cdcList xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <cdc>
        <idCdc xmlns="">2</idCdc>
        <idCdcParent xmlns=""/>
        <cdcName xmlns="">Roma</cdcName>
        <order xmlns="">1</order>
        <isUsed xmlns="">false</isUsed>
        <?xml-multiple cdcList?>
        <cdcList>
            <cdc>
                <idCdc xmlns="">5</idCdc>
                <idCdcParent xmlns="">2</idCdcParent>
                <cdcName xmlns="">Progetti</cdcName>
                <order xmlns="">2</order>
                <isUsed xmlns="">false</isUsed>
                <?xml-multiple cdcList?>
                <cdcList>
                    <cdc>
                        <idCdc xmlns="">17</idCdc>
                        <idCdcParent xmlns="">5</idCdcParent>
                        ... etc
```